# Android: navigation drawer without xml

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

Is it possible to create and add to app Navigation Drawer without using xml?
Every example i saw had an additional xml file with layout.
Nowadays i try to initialize this with:

```
DrawerLayout sidePanel = new DrawerLayout(this);
```

and then add this `sidePanel` using `View` method `addView()` but it cause exception.
Is it possible to add Navigation Drawer using only java code?

Comment: Does the navigation drawer not live in it's own fragment? I cannot see the advantage of this

Comment: OP, why would you not use an XML? What's the problem with adding an XML if it is how it works for everybody?

Comment: In fact i just wonder is it possible at all. Generaly i tought i can add everything stright from code (and until today it was true), but this one is some kind of exception from rule or i don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: @shkschneider not all app using xml for example the game (because it usually only contain 1 view / openGLView), and i also need to implement drawer in my game

Answer (score -1):

yes , you can do that without the XML, but still you would require a layout to at least hold that navigation drawer that you need

Comment: Can you give me some example? As i understand drawer contains some layout not inversely.

Comment: you need to create XML with Frame layout that will contain the fragments of your navigation drawer. an exemplary layout I have added above

Comment: This answer would be improved if you said **how** you achieve this. Simply saying yes isn't particularly helpful. Also you should avoid answering the same question twice.